# Error importing img_to_array. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-3.7

When I tried to import img_to_array from keras.preprocessing.image, I get the following error

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-084051e32a16> in <module>
----> 1 from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py in <module>
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in <module>
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11 

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in <module>
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in <module>
      3 from __future__ import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
      7 from tensorflow.python.framework import device as tfdev

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     37 # go/tf-wildcard-import
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
---> 39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
     41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context

c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

How to fix this? I am using Python-3.7 and tensorflow-2.4.1.
I have also downloaded msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll and placed in System32 folder but still could not resolve this error.

Please kindly help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file is missing.

Try update both to newest version.

Check if you have Numpy.

Update pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If versions do not work together , try reinstalling both (maybe something did not download during installation).